# Depending on interfaces instead of framework services

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, interface

For example I use `SomeFramework` which have `mechanism` to deal with controllers/actions. And I want to write `MyService` some methods of which depend on *current action name*.

Obviously I can do relation in `MyService` on `MechanismInterface` provided by `SomeFramework`.

But will it be better if I will create an interface `ActionResolver` and its implementation `SomeFrameworkActionResolver`?

`SomeFrameworkActionResolver` will depend on `MechanismInterface`, but `MyService` will depend on `ActionResolver` interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can do relation in `MyService` on `MechanismInterface` provided by `SomeFramework`.

It's not good because `MechanismInterface` still belongs to `SomeFramework` package, therefore `MyService` still depends *directly* on `SomeFramework` package.

> will it be better if I will create an interface `ActionResolver` and its implementation `SomeFrameworkActionResolver`?

Yeah, it's much better. Just put the `ActionResolver` interface belongs to the same package with `MyService`, and put `SomeFrameworkActionResolver` belong to another package. Now `MyService` and `SomeFramework` are totally decoupled. When you have to use new `SomeFramework2`, the `MyService` package remains stable.